# Twig: remove div around each checkbox fields of a form

Tags: twig, symfony

Edit: see the solution I've found at the end of my question ;-)

I'm looking since hours for a solution but I do not really find what I'like. I'm sure it is easy to do.

I'm building a form with Symfony 3.1. My form does not send anything in a database. Everything seems okay. But when rendering my twig template all my checkbox are surrounded by a `<div>` html tag.

I just would like twig renders me a form without that `<div>` tag.
edit: this is what Twig render me: this is ok for me but I would like to remove  div tags

```
<form name="form" method="post">
<div id="form"><div><label for="form_1">1</label><input type="checkbox" id="form_1" name="form[1]" class="ballsCheckBox" value="1" /></div>
</form>
```

Here is my twig template:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}SimulotoBundle:Lotto:lotto{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome to the Lotto:result page</h1>
{{form(form)}}

{% endblock %}
```

I build the form directly in a controller. See it:
    public function LottoSimulationFormAction()

```
   {
        $lt = new LottoSimulation();

        $data = [];

        $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($data);

        /** building Lotto grid with checkboxes * */
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $lt->getMaxNb(); $i++)
        {
            $formBuilder->add($i, CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => $i,
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'ballsCheckBox'
                ]
            ]);
        }

        /** adding submit button **/
        $formBuilder->add('Envoyer', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'save'
                ]
            ]);

        $form = $formBuilder->getForm();

        return $this->render("SimulotoBundle:Lotto:lotto.html.twig", [
            "form" => $form->createview()
                ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make your solution into an answer and self-accept it

Comment: It's done. I have created an answer. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the soluton to solve this problem.

I need to Customize the form rendering as it is explained in the Synfony cookBook on this page http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Go to vendor\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Ressources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html and modify the block:

```
{%- block form_row -%}
    <div>
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row -%}
```

You can remove it but a better way is to copy/past that block to your teplate and overide it. Like this:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% form_theme form _self %} //don't forget this line of code

{%- block form_row -%}
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
{%- endblock form_row -%}
```